# How to modify request data before saving / converting into entities?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, strip-tags

What is a suggested way to strip HTML tags before data save in CakePHP 3.2?

I'm building newEntity with `$this->request->data` (data come from the form) and later on, I'm using save function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Model.beforeMarshal` event/callback to modify data before it is being converted into entities.

From the docs:

> If you need to modify request data before it is converted into
>   entities, you can use the Model.beforeMarshal event. This event lets
>   you manipulate the request data just before entities are created:
>
> ```
> // In a table or behavior class
> public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, ArrayObject $data, ArrayObject $options)
> {
>    if (isset($data['username'])) {
>        $data['username'] = mb_strtolower($data['username']);
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> [...]

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Modifying Request Data Before Building Entities](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities)**

On a related note, don't forget *not* to rely on input sanitizing, always make sure to treat it as possibly unsafe when using/outputting the data!

Comment: Dang, what's the point of even using a framework if it doesn't automatically sanitize input?

Comment: @UncaAlby I can only assume that you're mixing up input sanitation with data binding in a ORM context, because having your framework automatically strip data like HTML tags from your input would be awful.

Comment: If it's all that awful add a flag to turn it off as needed. But default it to turned on. My point is simply, if I have to do the important stuff myself, why am I using a framework for what's supposed to be the heavy lifting?

Comment: @UncaAlby A framework isn't supposed to do everything for you, it cannot possibly protect you from all the pitfalls out there. You may want to read up on sanitizing input vs escaping output, and the role of validation, and if you then still think that's something that a web application framework should do out of the box, then please feel free to open an issue or a pull request over at https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp, but be prepared to be met with resistance.

Comment: Funny you should mention all of that, as it appears CakePHP 4 does it, or most of it anyway. I just ran into a CSRF error in Ajax, because I didn't know that had been activated. I'm still learning everything so now I have to figure out how to send the CSRF token in Ajax. But it does seem that, if you **want** the framework to do the heavy lifting it **can.** Which to me makes a lot more sense than forcing web developers to "roll their own." Where security is concerned, that's generally the **last** thing you want.

Comment: @UncaAlby CSRF and HTML request data are two very different things, the former is clearly an attack, an obvious security concern, the latter is perfectly acceptable data, which out of the box wouldn't do any harm as all baked templates will escape the output. Again, if you think having optional request data sanitizing functionality is something that the framework could benefit of, then please make your case over at github.

Comment: I'm just saying that where security is concerned, we should not force developers to roll their own. Most developers would do a poor job. As I said earlier, if you don't think you need to worry about a particular input, set the flag that says "don't worry about it." Elsewise, **everything** that needs to be done to keep the site safe should be the framework default. But I thank you for your opinion.